# How do I see all set shortcuts within Firefox?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

Is it possible to find a centralized location and/or listing of all set keyboard shortcuts used within Firefox, including keyboard shortcuts enabled by miscellaneous add-ons?

NOTES

I've seen Windows programs and utilities that can show the setting of system-wide keyboard shortcuts, but haven't found the ability to do this within a program, such as with Firefox.

Other than iterating individually through each and every add-on, is it possible to do this? If there isn't some type of add-on or utility that can do this, surely there must be some manner of centralized location somewhere in the system where these keyboard shortcuts are stored/accessed (e.g., registry, about:config settings, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a part answer. The shortcuts are listed here: [Mozilla shortcuts](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly) The problem with this part answer is it will probably become outdated quickly.

You could always [download this plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/)  and view the shortcuts currently in use in Firefox, but I'm not sure if this extends to other plugin's shortcuts.